# Most pythonic way to specify which object function to use in a function

Tags: python

I am setting a function where the user can specify how to initialize a variable. Here is a minimal example

```
def setValue( typeOf ):
    if typeOf == 'normal':
        a = np.random.normal( parameters)
    if typeOf == 'uniform':
        a = np.random.uniform(parameters)
```

However, in my real case, there are dozens of initialization options. I am wondering if I can make the code more elegant my specifying directly how the user wants to initialize the variable

```
def setValue( something ):
    something hapenng
    a = np.random.whatever_user_specified
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a question of being *pythonic* or not, but is rather a question of code design. There are multiple ways to achieve what you want, and your choice mainly depends on the function contract. That said, one approach would be to accept the initializing function as the argument:

```py
def setValue(distribution):
  a = distribution(parameters)

setValue(np.random.normal)
```

with the use of [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) you can fixate parameters of the initializer if necessary

```py
setValue(partial(np.random.normal, scale=1))
```

A different approach would be to have a static mapping between names and 
initializers:

```py
distribution = {
  'uniform': np.random.uniform,
  'normal': np.random.normal,
}

def setValue(name):
  a = distribution[name](parameters)

setValue('normal')
```

Finally, you can always use introspection to call the method indirectly

```py
def setValue(name):
  a = getattr(np.random, name)(parameters)

setValue('uniform')
```

but this is a subject to [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) and also is not secure if being run in an untrusted environment.

There are other approaches as well, but they are far more complicated and, as I said, mainly depend on the code design.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getattr` to fetch a function by name:

```
method = "uniform"
if method in ["normal", "uniform"]:
    func = getattr(np.random, method)
    func()
# => 0.10683518702441452
```

You could also be excepting `AttributeError`, but that might give a bit more access than you meant to give.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)?

```
def setValue(typeOf):
    func = getattr(np.random, typeOf)
    a = func(parameters)
```